# Question of linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, orthonormal

Given the matrices

$$M= \begin{bmatrix}
  5 & -\sqrt{3} \\
  -\sqrt{3} & 7 \\
  \end{bmatrix},$$

and
 $$N= \begin{bmatrix}
  6 & -2 \\
  -2 & 6 \\
  \end{bmatrix},$$

prove that there is a linear transformation $T ∈ L(R^2)$ and two orthonormal bases
$B=\{b_1,b_2\}$ and $V=\{v_1,v_2\}$, such that
$[T]^{B}=N$ and $[T]^{V}=M$.

I have to draw the bases and the eigenvectors of $T$.
Could someone help me with this question?

Answer (score 0):

It suffices to show that $M$ and $N$ are similar via an orthonormal matrix. This follows immediately, as they are symmetric and both have characteristic polynomial $x^2 - 12x + 32$.